# Entreprise distribution certificate renewal

Tags: ios, xcode

I have just renewed my client's enterprise distribution certificate which was about to expire in next 20 days. everything is working fine with new certificate but only issue which have seen is expiration date of new certificate which is after 3 years i.e. 2016.

i have read [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html) and it says "A distribution certificate is valid for one year from date of issue."
Does enterprise distribution certificate have 3 years of validity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your certificate may last 3 years but the provisioning profile you sign with it will only be valid for a year.  I ran in to this when we updated our apps this year.

Comment: yes,provisioning profile will get expire after 1 year.
but according to apple documentation even distribution certificate should get renewed with 1 year validity.
Have you observed similar thing while renewing your certificate?

Comment: Yes, this year ours renewed for longer than expected.